# Issue parsing JSON with ServiceStack.Text

Tags: c#, .net, json, servicestack

I'm using ServiceStack.Text to parse [WorldWeatherOnline's Marine Api](http://www.worldweatheronline.com/premium-weather.aspx?menu=marine).

When Deserialising the JSON the library parses the JSON incorrectly as you can see in the second column of the image below

[image]

This is a part the JSON  (Snipped for brevity)

```
{
"data":{
  "nearest_area":[
     {
        "distance_miles":"36.8",
        "latitude":"53.965",
        "longitude":"0.456"
     }
   ]
 }
}
```

And this is the class i'm trying to deserialize it to

```
 public class Weather
{
    public NearestArea NearestArea { get; set; }

}

public class NearestArea
{
    public double? RetLatitude { get; set; }
    public double? RetLongitude { get; set; }
    public double? MilesFromReq { get; set; }
}
```

This is the bit of code that's doing the deserialisation

```
Weather result = JsonObject.Parse(content).Object("data").ConvertTo(x=> new Weather{


                        NearestArea = x.Object("nearest_area").ConvertTo(n => new NearestArea{

                            MilesFromReq = Convert.ToDouble(n.Get("distance_miles")),
                            RetLatitude = Convert.ToDouble(n.Get ("latitude")),
                            RetLongitude = Convert.ToDouble(n.Get ("longitude"))

                        })
```

Can anyone spot the problem?

Comment: Doozer where are you getting the 'content'?  I'm trying to use a service as well but can't figure out ServiceStack enough to get the json string. Is there an example of consuming a service with service stack?

Comment: I'm not using Service Stack to get the content, i'm just using the standard .NET HttpWebResponse class. I think there's a few examples on the Gitub page  https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack

Comment: Thanks - Mythz ended up helping me here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13147048/353147

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below code should work...

```
var weather = ServiceStack.Text.JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromString<RootWeather>(content);


public class RootWeather
{
    public Weather data { get; set; }

}

public class Weather
{
    public List<NearestArea> nearest_area { get; set; }

}

public class NearestArea
{
    public string latitude { get; set; }
    public string longitude { get; set; }
    public string distance_miles { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: That does work, thank you, although all my properties are now strings rather than doubles. No way to get Service Stack to desrialize it the types that  i want?

Comment: @Doozer1979, they are between `"`s, so they are not numbers.

Comment: Also, Surely there must be someway in service stack  that i can map keys in the JSON to my types, without them having to have the same names?

Comment: @Doozer1979 just change them to `double?`, ServiceStack seems to be clever enough to do the conversion

Answer (score 0):

You may have also a look to the [DataContractJsonSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.aspx). This serializer is made for such jobs.

Basically you just need to define a class with some datamember attributes the rest is done automatically. See the example on the MSDN of [DataContractSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer.aspx) which do the same job just with xml.

Comment: Thanks,i'm specifically looking at ServiceStack.text for it's Performance, bt if i don't get any joy i'll take a look. I'm also going to be using it on Mono at some point. Not sure if the mono team have ported that library over yet.

Comment: When you say *use that class*,  you should say why it is better than the others. `DataContractSerializer`, personally, is my last preference.

Comment: I jused the class in a WCF environment. So far I know this class it's simple and works fine. Also you don't need to walk down the structure to get the data.

Comment: @rekire Other serializers make it too. And even with a single line. Even without decorating the class with attributes.

Comment: @L.B there are some advantages which I forgot just now... but if I guess right the most one have problems with a bigger structures. If you can help Doozer1979 better then me feel free to write your own answer.

Comment: @rekire Thanks for making me download the service stack and try it too. Now I know better  why I don't like DataContractJsonSerializer

Comment: @L.B Well fine that you find a solution for `ServiceStack.Text`, but I don't get the point why you seems to dislike `DataContractJsonSerializer` so much. What is wrong with that class of the .net framework? What is the advantage of using some external library instead of a build in feature?

Comment: IMHO Service Stack is fast but but the deserializer and serializer are buggy and too often doesn't work for me. Correctness is important too. JSON.NET is a well established (albeit a bit bloated IMHO) json library. FastJSON is appearantly quite fast as well but I am not sure about the correctness.

Comment: @rekire Other serializers(My favorite is Json.Net) provides much more flexibiliy when serializing/deserializing objects. Just search SO for Json.Net and see how people use it like swiss army knife