# Consuming Web Service HTTP Post

Tags: c#, http-post, servicestack

I'm consuming a web-service with [ServiceStack](http://servicestack.net).  The header expected is:

```
POST /SeizureWebService/Service.asmx/SeizureAPILogs HTTP/1.1
Host: host.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: length

jsonRequest=string
```

I'm trying to consume it with this code:

```
public class JsonCustomClient : JsonServiceClient
{
    public override string Format
    {
        get
        {
            return "x-www-form-urlencoded";
        }
    }

    public override void SerializeToStream(ServiceStack.ServiceHost.IRequestContext requestContext, object request, System.IO.Stream stream)
    {
        string message = "jsonRequest=";
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(stream, Encoding.Unicode))
        {
            sw.Write(message);
        }
        // I get an error that the stream is not writable if I use the above
        base.SerializeToStream(requestContext, request, stream);
    }
}

public static void JsonSS(LogsDTO logs)
{    
    using (var client = new JsonCustomClient())
    {
        var response = client.Post<LogsDTOResponse>(URI + "/SeizureAPILogs", logs);
    }
}
```

I can't figure out how to add the `jsonRequest=` before the serialized DTO.  How do I do this?

**Solution based on Mythz's answer**:

Added how I used Mythz's answer for someone having the same issue(s) in the future - enjoy!

```
public static LogsDTOResponse JsonSS(LogsDTO logs)
{
    string url = string.Format("{0}/SeizureAPILogs", URI);
    string json = JsonSerializer.SerializeToString(logs);
    string data = string.Format("jsonRequest={0}", json);
    var response = url.PostToUrl(data, ContentType.FormUrlEncoded, null);
    return response.FromJson<LogsDTOResponse>();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very weird use of a custom service client to send `x-www-form-urlencoded` data, I think this is a bit ambitious to try as ServiceStack's ServiceClients are meant to send/receive the same Content-type. Where as even though your class is called `JsonCustomClient` it's no longer a JSON client since you've overrided the the `Format` property.

The issue your having is likely using the `StreamWriter` in a using statement which would close the underlying stream. Also I expect you calling the base method to be an error since you're going to have an illegal mix of Url-Encoded + JSON content-type on the wire.

Personally I would steer clear of the ServiceClients and just use any standard HTTP Client, e.g. ServiceStack has some [extensions to WebRequest](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Http-Utils) that wraps the usual boilerplate required in making HTTP calls with .NET, e.g:

```
var json = "{0}/SeizureAPILogs".Fmt(URI)
           .PostToUrl("jsonRequest=string", ContentType.FormUrlEncoded);

var logsDtoResponse = json.FromJson<LogsDTOResponse>();
```

Comment: Thanks Mythz, I wanted to stay clear but the complexities of consuming a web-request made me want to try and figure it out with ServiceStack.  I'm glad you have those extensions, it is really appreciated.